# ensure bash command exits with 0 in if/fi block

Tags: bash, sh

I have been confused about this ever since I started writing bash scripts

```
YARN=$(which yarn)

if [ -z "${YARN}" ]; then
    npm install -g yarn &&
fi
```

the above gives a syntax error, but this won't:

```
if [ -z "${YARN}" ]; then
    npm install -g yarn &&
    echo "yarn installed"
fi
```

why is that?

and how can we ensure that if we do this instead:

```
if [ -z "${YARN}" ]; then
    npm install -g yarn
fi

echo "yarn installed"
```

that yarn will indeed be installed when the echo statement is invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a command after `&&`, in your case it should be `echo "yarn installed"`:

```
if [ -z "${YARN}" ]; then
    npm install -g yarn && echo "yarn installed"
fi
```

`&&` is a shell operator which indicates the shell to run the command after it iff the previous command succeeds (`$?==0`).